# single line text log file parsing

Tags: php, parsing, explode, delimiter, logfiles

So i have a log/txt file wich contains the following :

```
31 dec. 2014 11:56 - UserA: Hi31 dec. 2014 11:56 - UserB: Hi to you31 dec. 2014 11:56 - UserA: Whats your name?31 dec. 2014 11:57 - UserB: Nancy
```

Im trying to get this into a more readable format.....
So im trying the following :

```
<?php
//load the logfile
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$txtfile2 = preg_split( "/ ( |:) /", $txt_file );
$rows = explode("\n", $txtfile2[0]);

foreach($rows as $row => $data)
{
$row_data = explode(':', $data);


$info[$row]['when']           = $row_data[0];
$info[$row]['name']         = $row_data[1];
$info[$row]['description']  = $row_data[2];


//display data
echo ' WHEN: ' . $info[$row]['when'] . '<br />';
echo ' WHO: ' . $info[$row]['name'] . '<br />';
echo ' MESSAGE: ' . $info[$row]['description'] . '<br /><br />';

}
?>
```

This works partially....
When executed the output would be :

WHEN: ﻿31 dec. 2014 11
WHO: 56 - UserA
MESSAGE: Hi

WHEN: 31 dec. 2014 11
WHO: 56 - UserB
MESSAGE: Hi to you

This is close to what i want, but as you can see, because im using the delimiter ":" it will also cut the time and place the minutes in the who.
How can i explode on the second ":" only?

i hope this makes sense?

Comment: Whats the delimiter between records? Is it a newline that's not showing in the sample data?

Comment: Hmm wait i just realise , im doing the explode on a newline.... So yes, there are new lines after each entry even though it doesnt show like a /n, seeing that the explode does chop it op into the correct parts

Comment: Is there a way to replace the first occurrence of ":" in each run of the foreach with a space or a "." for all i care?

Comment: Did that answer work for you?

Comment: Im going to test it in about 4 hours or so (if i dont forget , thnx in advance man ! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how this works for you

```
    <?php
    $filename = "logfile.txt"; //data file to open
    $fp = fopen( $filename, "r" ) or die("Couldn't open $filename");
    while ( ! feof( $fp ) )
        {
        $line = fgets( $fp, 1024 );
        $line_array = preg_split("/[:-]+/", $line);
        $line_timestamp = $line_array[0] . ":" . $line_array[1];
        $line_user = $line_array[2];
        $line_message = $line_array[3];
        echo ' WHEN: ' . $line_timestamp . '<br />';
        echo ' WHO: ' . $line_user . '<br />';
        echo ' MESSAGE: ' . $line_message . '<br /><br />';
        }
   ?>
```